# Using Sockets with NSXPCConnection

Tags: tcpserver, entitlements, xpc, cfsocket, nsxpcconnection

Running into an issue when using sockets with an NSXPCConnection.

Basically, there is a main process and a helper process running, established via NSXPCConnection. That helper process needs to act as a server and listen to a particular port (say 111), which receives outside connections.

The helper process opens a listening socket using the `TCPServer` helper class (wrapper around `CFSocket`) which is provided by Apple. Code found here:
https://code.google.com/p/iphone-remotepad/source/browse/trunk/RemotePad/TCPServer.h?r=238

The socket is opened successfully in `- (BOOL)start:(NSError **)error`.

The outer clients can establish with the 111 port. (test in terminal via `telnet localhost 111`).

However, the helper process never receives the TCPServer callback `TCPServerAcceptCallBack`.

The helper process has `com.apple.security.network.client` entitlement enabled.

Also, when I run the TCPServer in the main app instead of the helper process,  set up the server on port 111, and try to connect to port 111, I do get the callback.

Any ideas of why the helper process does not receive socket call back? An XPC related issue?

Answer (score 1):

Ok figured out the issue.

An xpc service provides you with a default run loop of type dispatch_main.

You want to substitute that with an NSRunLoop - done by changing the xpc service info plist:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingXPCServices.html

Once that is done, you want to manually create a run loop inside your xpc service, along lines of:

```
do {
    @autoreleasepool {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]run];
    }
} while (YES);
```

With that in place, the TCPServer (which needs an active runloop) will return the callback and you'll be able to get the incoming data.